# Remote Debugging Go REST Endpoints

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, delve

I am new to Go and new to VSCode. I have also never used Delve before. I am trying to set up remote debugging but i can't seem to hit breakpoints.

My project hosts REST endpoints on localhost:8080. What should the launch.json file look like in order to have delve attach and listen so that I can put breakpoints on my REST endpoints? Currently, this is what i have:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "go",
        "request": "launch",
        "mode": "remote",
        "remotePath": "",
        "port": 8080,
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "env": {},
        "args": [],
        "showLog": true
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://blog.gobuffalo.io/debugging-a-buffalo-app-in-gogland-b9a00e8076b8) mentioned:

Unfortunately, you won’t be able to debug an application when running with buffalo dev. You’ll need to build an executable that skips compiler optimizations like function invocation inlining.
**If you skip these build flags Gogland won’t stop on your break points**.

More on that on "[Debugging Go Code with GDB](https://golang.org/doc/gdb#Introduction) ".

> The code generated by the gc compiler includes inlining of function invocations and registerization of variables. These optimizations can sometimes make debugging with gdb harder.

After that, you can follow "[Remote Debugging](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/Debugging-Go-code-using-VS-Code#remote-debugging)"

> To remote debug using VS Code, you must first run a headless Delve server on the target machine. For example:

```
$ dlv debug --headless --listen=:2345 --log
```

*Then* your launcher can apply.

Comment: still no luck :( i am also now seeing problems in the laucnh.json file saying type go definition cannot be found

Comment: @BigBug Do you have the go plugin installed in your VSCode instance?